# Get User from "After updating an existing og membership" event using Drupal 7 Rules

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-rules

I have the current event "After updating an existing og membership" in Drupal 7 using the Rules module. Would I would like to do is get the User whose og membership was just updated using Actions, I can only get the current site user by default. I would greatly appreciate anyone who could help me with this or tell me what php code I would need to make this work too. I want to be able to add a role to the user after their profile is updated by an admin.

Is there a module that adds rules that could help me?

Is there anyway to get the user whose membership was just updated?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try **Tokens** module.

It can help you to take the user associated with the updated og membership.

https://www.drupal.org/project/token